# 'Strange' issue with stuck subsampling iteration scheme (using try(...))

Tags: r, random

I am doing a subsampling task in R 2.15.3 on a Linux Machine (server),
where there occur errors in some subsampling iterations (which are just due to unsuitable subsampled data sets).

To be able to run many subsampling iterations without the loop to
stop, in each iteration I use `try()` in the following way:

```
set.seed(1234)

interestingobject <- list()

for(i in 1:300) {

  anyproblems <- try(0 + "0")

  while(class(anyproblems) == "try-error") {

    anyproblems <- try({

      <code line 1>
      <code line 2>
      <code line 3>
        .
        .
        .

    })

  }

  interestingobject[[i]] <- <object from iteration i>

}
```

Now I have the following 'strange' problem:

After a few iterations the first error occurs in
`try({ ... })`. I would think that this is no problem
since the 'while'-loop should continue until no error
in `try({ ... })` happens anymore.
But the problem is that after the first error occurred,
the same error happens again and again, since the same
samples are drawn and I don't know why.

UPDATE: When before the line "code line 1" I just draw
a random number (`cat(runif(1), "\n")`) inside `try({ ... })`
the code proceeds until the end, but one gets into a loop, meaning
that the elements in "interestingobject" are repeating every couple
of iterations.
I really don't know how this happens.
I suppose that the problem could be somehow explained by something related to
 the way R generates/handles random numbers (or something like this).

It seems probably a bit difficult without the exact code, however
the latter would probably not help much since it is rather 
long and confusing.

How might it be explained that something like this happens?

The random number drawn is also repeated in the loop, so really the
same thing is repeated every couple of iterations.

EDIT (PROBABLY NOT IMPORTANT FOR THE ISSUE): Some specifications on the code:
In each iteration there is a cross validation done, whereby there is also a nested cross validation, where - using cross validation- a tuning parameter is optimized in each outer cross validation iteration.

Maybe it is of worth knowing that the tuning of the tuning parameter - and therefor also the random splitting into the folds in the corresponding cross validation - is done by a
self-written function defined outside the code.

UPDATE 2: Thanks to the commenters, I have now used debugging and found that at the spot were the first error occurs (only observations from one class) and where the loop starts one also gets the warning:

In get(.obj, envir = dump[[.selection]]) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation

Maybe this helps. What can this warning message mean? Is maybe the seed of the random number generator reset?

Comment: Where does your while loop increment??   (if that is in one of the omitted lines of code, it might be relevant to include it)

Comment: I think you should show some of the content of the `while` loop.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta: Sorry, the spacing was not good, now I corrected it. The while-loop should just continue until no error in "code line 1", "code line 2", ... occurs anymore.

Comment: @Thomas: I will have a look, how I can extract some of the content in a meaningfull way. A problem might be that it also contains self-written functions stored elsewhere, the use of which is not really clear from the code.

Comment: From the way you describe it, you may actually want a series of `try` commands rather a bunch of code wrapped in a single `try`.

Comment: @user2654097, no prob.  My question was where does the while loop increment.  It is still not clear where that happens and I suspect it is missing from the code altogether

Comment: @Thomas: I had used more than one "try" commands in the past, but when I did a very error-prone simulation once I figured out that one could just put the whole code into "try", so the whole iteration is just done anew in case any error occurs in the iteration. But maybe one should consider more than one "try" commands again here to fix the problem.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta: The "while" loop does not include a counter, it just continues until the object "anyproblems" is not of class "try-error" anymore, which is the case when no error occurs in "code line 1", "code line 2",... anymore.

Comment: I am using the word increment loosely and perhaps shouldnt.  I simply mean, what is the difference between one iteration and the next?  Can you please show that difference in your code.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta: Sorry, I got you wrong. The differences are: 1) There is a different value of a
tuning parameter involved, which is due to the fact that it is optimized using
cross validation whereby we use a different splitting into training and test sets involved.
2) A second cross validation loop is involved, in which also the tuning parameter
is optimized itself on each learning set using cross validation, i.e. a nested cross
validation scheme.

I'm sorry that the explanation might not be that clear, however it would be very delicate to explain the whole topic.

Comment: @Thomas: I just tried to post the code, but got a message that it would be too long. I hope to find a way to make some excerpts in an enlightening way.

Comment: Perhaps something is meant to converge and is not?   Either way, **something** is meant to change in the while loop from what you describe does not.  This is just a basic debugging issue and identifying where the error is.   If the code is too long to paste, it is probably too long to ask someone to sift through and find the bug ;)

Comment: There is no convergence scheme involved.
The main reason why I posted the problem here, was the strange fact,
that it worked when I included this one line with the additional
random number generation "cat(runif(1), "\n")" and not when I left
it out.
Therefor I thought that the problem might be somehow deeper
and could be explained by something related to the way R handles
random numbers (or something like this).
I will edit the post now to make this clearer.

Comment: What happens when you change the initial seed? Does the problem go away?

Comment: Time to put `browser()` inside your innermost `try` loop. That way you can check the output of your `code line X` and observe something happening (or not happening) that you didn't expect.

Comment: @Thomas: I now changed the initial seed, but the same thing happens only
beginning at a different iteration. I also noticed that, while adding the line
with the random number drawing indeed makes the code proceed, BUT one ends
up in a loop, meaning that the elements in "interestingobject" are repeating
every couple of iterations. I have no idea, why this happens. I will note this
in the post.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: It is clear that there is an error in some iterations (e.g. because the 
subsampled training data set cannot be handled by a specific method) and I want
to simply drop these cases and make new divisions in training and test data sets.
I already know from the output on the console which error occured. So if an error occurs,
this iteration should just be "forgotten" and a new iteration made.

Comment: I think from your answers, it's pretty clear your while loop is not achieving its intended purpose. Perhaps play around with just advancing the for-loop to its next iteration on every try-error and see if it otherwise works. I'll also second @CarlWitthoft on going for `browser()`.

Comment: That's my point -- the iteration **should** be dropped, but it **isn't** .  That means your code is not producing the results you expect, hence the reason for dropping into `browser` to find out why.

Comment: Thank you, with debugging I have now found that there is a warning where the first error occurs, which might be related to the problem of the loop, I have written it at the end of the post.

Answer (score -2):

Since I have no better solution, I did an ugly workaround now, where
the random seed it set anew each time the procedure in try({...}) is repeated,
whether there has been an error or not.
Since the randomly chosen seeds would themselves be subject to the problem
that the random numbers are in a loop, they are drawn before the whole
subsampling starts:

```
set.seed(1234)

interestingobject <- list()

########
# New: #
########
ranseed <- sample(1000000:10000000, size=100000)
count <- 1
#######

for(i in 1:300) {

  anyproblems <- try(0 + "0")

  while(class(anyproblems) == "try-error") {

    ########
    # New: #
    ########
    set.seed(ranseed[count])
    count <- count+1
    ########

    anyproblems <- try({

      <code line 1>
      <code line 2>
      <code line 3>
        .
        .
        .

    })

  }

  interestingobject[[i]] <- <object from iteration i>

}
```

Since this is obviously only a coarse solution I would still be
very happy if somebody could give a tip what might happen there!

In the code inside try({ ... }) I do not set a seed. However maybe
there is something going on in the functions from the packaged code
I use: "rfCMA" from the package "CMA", which itself uses "randomForest" 
from the package of the same name "rfCMA". "mtry" in the Random Forests
is optimized with the function "tune" also from the "CMA"-package.

EDIT: I checked the code inside try({...}) again and could find no bug. If somebody thinks that the above solution might be wrong, please tell! I can't see why it might be wrong, since every time an error occurs inside try({...}) the corresponding iteration is discarded and through set.seed(ranseed[count]) it is ascertained that a completely independent one is drawn.